# 1st Yr Probability: Is the book solution wrong? Optimal bidding against other bids that are uniform random

Tags: probability

**Problem**

You and three other people are to place bids for an object, with the high bid winning. If you win, you plan to sell the object immediately for 10 thousand dollars. How much should you bid to maximize your expected profit if you believe that the bids of the others can be regarded as being independent and uniformly distributed between 7 and 11 thousand dollars?

**My issue with book solution**

I could be wrong but I think there is a typo in the book solution (see below).

The book solution says that the expected profit is maximized when the bid is $x=37/4=9.25$ and if I plug this into $E[G(9.25)] = 2.13$. So if you bid $9.25$ your expected profit is $2.13$ thousand dollars. However, if you bid $9.25$ the most you can make is $10-9.25=.75$ which is less than the expected profit.

I think the typo (red circle) should be fixed to:

$$E[G(x)] = \bigg(\frac{x-7}{4}\bigg)^3(10-x)$$

The author Sheldon Ross is a math god compared to me so it's very possible this is not a typo and I am wrong. That's totally cool too. If so please explain the book answer to me, this problem drove me crazy for like an hour.

**Book solution below**

[image]

Comment: By the way, my interpretation is $X$ is a Bernoulli RV with $p=(\frac{x-7}{4})^3$ and $G(X) = 10-X$ if you win and $0$ otherwise therefore the $$E[G(x)] = (\frac{x-7}{4})^3(10-x) + [1-(\frac{x-7}{4})^3]*0$$

Comment: @poyea True, but not what the OP is asking.  He thinks this is the wrong function.

Comment: @HJ_beginner Maybe it's a typo. $\left(\dfrac{1}{4}(x-7)^3(10-x)\right)'=0$ and  $\left(\left(\dfrac{x-7}{4}\right)^3(10-x)\right)'=0$ give the same solution.

Comment: Yes, it's probably a typo. Note that both functions have the same maxima, so the value is correct, and you should just substitute it in the correct expression.

Comment: Yes I agree that the optimal bid is $9.25$ as the book solution says. But the expected value of this optimal bid is $16$ times larger than it should be. Can you confirm? Also, what do you think of my interpretation of the full formula for $E[G(x)]$ in the comments. Is that correct? Specifically I am unsure of what $G(x)$ is. Thanks.

Comment: I think the book has factored the 4 in the denominator out incorrectly, it factored it out of the cubed bracket as 1/4 instead of 1/64 - hence the error of 16 fold

Comment: looks like an error in their algebra -  a mistake, not a typo $E[G(x)] = (\frac{x-7}{4})^3(10 - x) = \frac{1}{64}(x-7)^3(10-x)$

Comment: @Cato and all. Thanks for your input... it helps to get other opinions... there have been book solutions that I thought were wrong but actually I was wrong (unsurprisngly).

Comment: no the book either made a mistake in algebra, or it was a typo in removing the 6 from 64